# How to store converted JSON data to CoreData?

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

so i'm making an exercise app. And at the moment i'm working on implementing an exercise database into my app. I'm getting the exercises from a JSON file which i stored locally on the app bundle. And then i'm trying to convert the JSON and extract the image url (string), exercise name (string) and exercise description (string). I then want to store that information into CoreData somehow. So i can then retrieve the data later on and display it into a table view. I've tried different methods of trying to accomplish this like using an array but nothing works. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: Normally you'd declare Core Data entities that are appropriate to model the data contained in the JSON, and create those entities as needed when parsing the JSON.

Comment: So the best option is to just go through and manually add the entities for each object from the JSON?

Comment: Not manually. Run through the array of data from JSON, and create a new instance at each pass.

Comment: Thanks for the response